# Merge two arrays as key value pairs in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I've got two arrays of the same size.  I'd like to merge the two so the values of one are the key indexes of the new array, and the values of the new array are the values of the other.

Right now I'm just looping through the arrays and creating the new array manually, but I have a feeling there is a much more elegant way to go about this.  I don't see any array functions for this purpose, but maybe I missed something?  Is there a simple way to this along these lines?

```
$mapped_array = mapkeys($array_with_keys, $array_with_values);
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

See [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/array_combine) on PHP.net.

Answer (score 17):

(from the docs for easy reading)

array_combine — Creates an array by using one array for keys and another for its values

**Description**

`array array_combine ( array $keys , array $values )`

Creates an array by using the values from the keys array as keys and the values from the values array as the corresponding values.

**Parameters**

keys - Array of keys to be used. Illegal values for key will be converted to string.

values - Array of values to be used

**Example**

```
<?php
$a = array('green', 'red', 'yellow');
$b = array('avocado', 'apple', 'banana');
$c = array_combine($a, $b);

print_r($c);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [green]  => avocado
    [red]    => apple
    [yellow] => banana
)
```

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick

```
function array_merge_keys($ray1, $ray2) {
    $keys = array_merge(array_keys($ray1), array_keys($ray2));
    $vals = array_merge($ray1, $ray2);
    return array_combine($keys, $vals);
}
```

Comment: Is this code-only answer solving some other question that I don't see?  The `array_merge()` calls have nothing to do with the OP's question and the `array_combine()` call was already suggested more than 1 year earlier.  I reckon this answer can be safely removed.