# combine two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Elegant way to merge two arrays as key value pairs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162032/elegant-way-to-merge-two-arrays-as-key-value-pairs-in-php)

I have two arrays:

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => B
    [2] => C
    [3] => D
    [4] => E
)

Array
(
    [0] => APPLE
    [1] => BANANNA
    [2] => CRANBERRY
    [3] => DURIAN
    [4] => EGGPLANT
)
```

I want to combine them so that first value of the first array will be the the first key of the second array.

```
Array
(
    [A] => APPLE
    [B] => BANANNA
    [C] => CRANBERRY
    [D] => DURIAN
    [E] => EGGPLANT
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Could do it with [array_combine](http://php.net/array_combine):

```
$new=array_combine($a, $b);
```

or roll your own:

```
$new=array();
foreach($a as $idxA=>$valA)
{
   $new[$valA]=$b[$idxA];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array1 = Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => B
    [2] => C
    [3] => D
    [4] => E
);

$array2 = Array
(
    [0] => APPLE
    [1] => BANANNA
    [2] => CRANBERRY
    [3] => DURIAN
    [4] => EGGPLANT
);

$answer = array_combine($array1, $array2);
print_r($answer);
```